# Google Translator Button Not Appearing At All

Tags: javascript, html, translation, google-translate, google-translation-api

I will make my website multilingual. As an easiest way to accomplish this, I am trying to add an Google Translator Widget. I have found some script to put on an HTML file but that doesn't work for me. Is there something I am missing or Google deactivated this?

Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title> Google Translater for Website </title> 
</head> 
<body>
<h2>Your Web Page</h2>
 <p>Click on the dropdown button to translate.</p>
 <p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function googleTranslateElementInit() {
 new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
 }
</script>
<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the output of this file:

[image]

Have any idea? Please share it. Thank you.

Comment: Another point that confuses me. I have another index.html file which is written months ago (IDK exact time). But It works as it should be. It has Google translate widget displaying and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Problem is that to run this on a online website we need to use HTTPS protocol.
Without that it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me,
try to run it in incognito mode and try it
maybe some extensions are preventing it from showing

Comment: Right, the code also works in an online html editor. But not on my browser, neither on incognito mode (where all extensions disabled) nor in Safari. Thank you for help, problem continues.

Answer (score 0):

Google has discontinued Google Translate widget.  It might work on some websites (where it had been used for years) but won't work for new installations / websites that haven't had it before.

Comment: Actually, it stills work. But it is hard to fix bugs as there is no official support or wide community.